# Change Value of a Parent Cell based on value of all child cells

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping somebody can help.

I have the following data. Basically i want to write a formula/macro to be able to change status of Parent when all the child are closed. e.g as all child (1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4) of parent 1 are closed, the parent 1's status should be closed. I am not sure how to do that.

```
Key Type    Status Parent Code
1   Parent   Open       1
1.1 Child   Closed      1
1.2 Child    Closed     1
1.3 Child   Closed      1
1.4 Child    Closed     1
2   Parent  Open        2
2.1 Child   Closed      2
2.2 Child   Open        2
2.3 Child   Open        2
```

Comment: Maybe you look for Gant Chart? https://cdn.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/Images/excel-gantt-chart-template-free.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table starts from the A1 cell, you can put this formula into a new column, E2, and fill down:

`=IF(B2="Parent",IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,"Child",$C$2:$C$10,"Closed",$D$2:$D$10,D2)=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,"Child",$D$2:$D$10,D2),"Closed","Open"),"")`

[image]

If you need to fill in the blanks in your Status column, you could auto-filter on Type = Parent and then put in a formula in the visible Status column fields:

`=E1`

Comment: Thanks heaps. Works great

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, ParentKey As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim booClose As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("C2:C" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

            If InStr(1, .Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, ".") = 0 Then

                MsgBox "You are trying to manually change Parent Status."

            Else

                ParentKey = Mid(.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, 1, InStr(1, .Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, "."))

                For i = 2 To LastRow

                    If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, ".") <> 0 Then

                        If Mid(.Cells(i, 1).Value, 1, InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, ".")) = ParentKey Then

                            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Closed" Then

                                booClose = True

                            Else

                                booClose = False

                                Exit For

                            End If

                        End If

                    End If

                Next i

                For i = 2 To LastRow

                    If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, ".") = 0 Then

                        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = ParentKey Then

                            Application.EnableEvents = False

                                If booClose = True Then
                                    .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Closed"
                                    Exit For
                                Else
                                    .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Open"
                                    Exit For
                                End If

                            Application.EnableEvents = True

                        End If

                    End If

                Next i

            End If

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```